# How exactly do we define devotion?

Tags: bhakti, terminology

I would like to understand the definition of the term 'devotion' from two different perspective:

1. Bachelor person (brahmchari)
2. Married person

Reason is that as a bachelor you are free to opt for any path if you are seeking spiritual growth, but as a married man you have constraints so obviously the definition of devotion varies for them.

How do we come to a conclusion that a person be it a bachelor or a married guy is totally devoted? What are the parameters that will eventually define it?

Comment: Do you mean What is Bhakti?

Comment: @Pandya In a way yes.

Comment: Shandilya Bhakti Sutras defines it well.